# What actually is a continuous charge distribution?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, classical-electrodynamics

I am well aware of the maths of how to do all sorts of calculations using continuous charge distributions (like volume, space, and, line charge distributions) but when I think about it I couldn't get it. What is, really, a continuous charge distribution?

Comment: What's the problem with it exactly?

Comment: I am unable to visualize it.

Comment: @bluesquare Just visualize it in the same way you visualize a *mass* distribution. After all, mass is just the gravitational charge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though a continuous charge distribution does not exist in nature, it is a very useful concept in situations where there are so many very small charge carriers that you don't see them individually.

Think of it like water. If you are not using sophisticated tools, you can't see the molecules. It looks continuous. Hydrodynamics is the study of the water at such a level of approximation. A continuous charge distribution is similar to the density of your fluid.

Comment: So this is completely a classical concept?

Comment: Not necessarily, there are situations where quantum effects have a mean, many-particle effect, see e.g. [Bose-Einstein condensation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate). It really is about coarse-graining the fine scale details of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

a discrete charge distribution is approximated by a continious charge distribution if the ratio
$$ \frac{\bar{d}}{D} << 1 $$
for $D$ the smallest diameter of the distribution and $\bar{d}$ the mean distance of discrete charges in any subvolume of the distribution (e.g this ratio has to be small in any subvolume of the distribution).

Comment: This is really a good answer to be upvoted. The ratio tells everything.+1

Comment: Can you refer to any quantitative proofs of your statement?